# Paypal payment after feedback

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

Dear Paypal/online service payment expert,

I'm building an app based on the interaction between shoppers and merchants.

So far so good! I have this scenario I need to understand how to make it and what service to use (paypal?):

1) the shopper contact the merchant through my app and ask for a service. They agree on a price.

2) the shopper pay the app (NOT the merchant!).

3) the merchant after X days/weeks completes the service to the shopper.

4) the shopper is happy and click on a button "RELEASE PAYMENT"; the app then release the payment to the merchant.

A couple of questions:

1) Does paypal supports this scenario?

2) what is the best practice for such problems?

Comment: isn't this basically escrow?

Comment: escrow ? I'm pretty new on this so I will investigate, thanks! do you know is Paypal support this?